# Out of memory with CPLEX QP optimization on matlab, although i have 80GB free

Tags: matlab, cplex

I am trying to solve a QP with CPLEX (academic license) on matlab, and I get out of memory error. Although I have 80 GB of free mem. I am sure I am running 64 bit version, because I see that the memory consumption is 10-15GB.

I tried increasing the 'workmem' parameter to 50e3, but it didn't help.

On a different machine, that I usually don't have access to, running the same code, with matlab's quadprog instead of cplexqcp takes 20-30GB.

Any idea how to solve make more memory available to the cplex qp solver?

PS: nnz for H/Aeq =~ 10e6, dimensions are approx 11e6 x 11e6

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. We do machine learning in big scales.

Comment: type `memory` in MATLAB. There is not only maximum memory that it can us, there is also maximum memory pervariable. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Thanks, but `memory` is not available on linux platforms.

Comment: Have you told CPLEX to use a compressed node file? (NodeFileInd = 3). Also, if I understand correctly, the workmem parameter works in the reverse direction to how you think. If you set it too high then it will crash with an OutOfMemory exception, but if you leave it low then it will use the node file. It's best to leave the parameter alone. Depth-first search also helps in these cases. There's a section "Running Out of Memory" in the IBM CPLEX manual that's worth a thorough read.